# Why doesn't Logger output to STDOUT get redirected to files?

Tags: ruby, logging

This script is named `o.rb`:

```
@logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
@logger.info "start_time : #{start_time}"
```

When I run it using `./o.rb`, the output on the console is correct.
However, when I tried `./o.rb > log.txt 2>&1`, the log file is empty!
Why did this happen?

I have the same issue while using the simple `puts` function.

---

UPDATE

This will reproduce this issue:

```
require 'logger'

logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)

loop do
  logger.info "This is a test haha"
  sleep(1)
end
```

When I run it using `./foo.rb`, it writes correctly to the console output.

When I run `./foo.rb > log.txt`, I get nothing.

Also, when I use `./foo.rb | tee log.txt`, nothing is written to the console and the log file is empty.

The log.txt file was created but remains empty.

My Ruby version is 1.8.7.

Comment: My program will keeps running maybe for 1 day, is it caused by the file buffers not flushed? Just now I write a simple script that only output one sentence and the program exit, it works.

Comment: I don't think it is buffering; [`LogDevice::new`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/logger/rdoc/Logger/LogDevice.html#method-c-new) calls [`@dev.sync = true`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html#method-i-sync-3D) -- which asks for unbuffered operation.

Comment: Do you have permission to write to that file (or the containing directory, if the file doesn't already exist)?

Comment: I have the permission. Not only the Logger but also 'puts', My program will output 1 sentence per 10 seconds on console. But when I redirect it to file by '>' or 'tee', and wait for 1 minute, NOTHING! I feel very strange.

Comment: Can you make a very simple program that we can run to reproduce the problem?

Comment: It's definitely buffering, remove the time delay and you'll see the file start growing.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's a buffering problem, you can set the standard output to sync and this should resolve it.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'logger'

$stdout.sync = true
logger = Logger.new($stdout)

loop do
  logger.info "This is a test haha"
  sleep 1
end
```

Comment: it works. but why outputting to console does not have this issue(without redirecting)?

Comment: Not sure, Bash must buffer the file descriptor when standard output isn't a tty.